# How to generate Soap Envelope and body for a class generated using XSD.exe in C#

Tags: c#, soap

I have one XSD which in turn  use multiple XSDs. I have generated .cs file using XSD.exe. Webservice Operation which i would like to call expect request XML is of this class type. Problem i am facing is that host of this webservice expect a XML with soap envelope and Soap Body. When i have generated XML using serializing the object of .cs file, it does not have soap envelope and body. 
I have tried finding this on net but nothing fruitful found.

### Expected XML:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soap:Header><wsse:Security soap:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd"><wsse:UsernameToken><wsse:Username>testuser</wsse:Username><wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">testwelcome1</wsse:Password></wsse:UsernameToken></wsse:Security></soap:Header>
    <soap:Body xmlns:ns1="http://capabilities.nat.bt.com/xsd/EDM/EMP/ManageDocument/CreateFolder">
        <ns1:CreateFolderRequest xmlns:ns2="http://wsi.nat.bt.com/2005/06/StandardHeader/" xmlns:ns3="http://capabilities.nat.bt.com/xsd/EDM/EMP/ManageDocument/Header/1.0">
            <ns2:standardHeader>
                <ns2:serviceState>
                    <ns2:stateCode>OK</ns2:stateCode>
                </ns2:serviceState>
                <ns2:serviceAddressing>
                    <ns2:from>Dummy</ns2:from>
                    <ns2:to>
                        <ns2:address>Dummy/ns2:address>
                    </ns2:to>
                    <ns2:replyTo>
                        <ns2:address>Dummy</ns2:address>
                    </ns2:replyTo>
                    <ns2:messageId>MessageID1</ns2:messageId>
                    <ns2:serviceName>Dummy</ns2:serviceName>
                    <ns2:action>AddDocumentRequest</ns2:action>
                </ns2:serviceAddressing>
            </ns2:standardHeader>
            <ns3:HeaderRequest>
                <ns3:AccountID>sharePoint_user</ns3:AccountID>
                <ns3:Password>Dummy</ns3:Password>
                <ns3:Domain>Dummy</ns3:Domain>
            </ns3:HeaderRequest>
            <ns1:RepositoryID>Dummy</ns1:RepositoryID>
            <ns1:FolderName>test_test_test_1</ns1:FolderName>
            <ns1:ParentID>null</ns1:ParentID>
            <ns1:CreatedDate>2012-03-02</ns1:CreatedDate>
            <ns1:OwnerID>null</ns1:OwnerID>
            <ns1:ParentPath>Test_Folder</ns1:ParentPath>
        </ns1:CreateFolderRequest>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Please help. sorry but i am new to this SOAP thing.

Comment: What about [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5wt2he6(v=vs.100).aspx) msdn how-to or this code-project [article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11079/NET-XML-and-SOAP-Serialization-Samples-Tips)?